# Использование history (HTML 5) + ajax

Tags: history, javascript, history-api, html5, html5-history-api

В общем не совсем понимаю принцип работы history,точнее не совсем понимаю, как мне реализовать это на моём сайте.

Имеется контент и в нём ссылка с определенным классом.  При клике на ссылку jquery отлавливает, так скажем, этот клик, копирует контент, открывает заведомо спрятанный ещё один див, вставляет в него контент, дополнительно подгружая из БД ЕЩЁ информацию в этот "открытый" див и меняет в строке адреса, собственно, адрес. При клике ВНЕ дива (он не очень большой), этот див скрывается и адресная строка меняется на начальный сайт.

А теперь вопрос по history. То, что выше - оно у меня работает хорошо, правильно, НО. Я не смог прикрутить такое, чтобы при нажатии на "назад" у меня в обратном порядке воспроизводились действия по открытию/закрытию окна пользователем.

Как я себе представляю работу с history: только что задумался и совсем запутался. Ну да ладно, попробую мысли разобрать - вот открываю сайт, запоминается его текущее состояние, при клике на ссылку открывается окно, меняется адрес. Если в браузере нажать "назад", то адрес изменится на предыдущий, славно, НО окно открытое не закрывается. Надо чтоб закрывалось. Пытался понять, как это сделать с помощью API - не понял:)

Понимаю, что надо это делать с помощью

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e){
...
}, false);
```

Но не совсем понимаю, что надо писать в теле функции, по видимому, надо писать ту функцию, которая окошко закрывает у меня (А с другой стороны - а если я его закрыл и тыкая назад хочу чтобы оно вернулось?). И вообще не знаю, в какой момент addEvent делать этот. Кто-то делает при window.onload, кто-то просто где-то будто с потолка... Объясните?

Если что, если нужно, алгоритм работы скрипта примерно такой.

1. При клике на ссылку открываем скрытый див, там проверки делаем типа был пустой, не был, все дела, дальше при нужных условиях запускаем функцию "клонирования" дива. Если инфа уже такая есть, то чтобы лишних запросов в БД не было, мы ничего не делаем кроме history.pushState(...) для того, чтобы при втором, третьем, десятом и т.д. открытии-закрытии окошка менялась адресная строчка (иначе только один раз работает из функции ниже).
2. Функция клонирования дива копирует инфу на "открытый" див и ajax-ом подгружает доп. инфу. Тут же делается history.pushState(...)
3. После отработки этой функции запускается функция закрытия окна, если был клик вне "открытого" дива. Так же имеется в этой функции функция history.pushState(...) которая подставляет адрес который типа до момента открытия окна был.

Вот в какое место ставить popstate? И какую функцию в нём запускать? Не могу пока разобраться. Надеюсь навашу помощь. Либо на то, что всё же получится самому разобраться.

Comment: Совсем совсем никто не знает?

Answer (score 1):

Упрощу, что вам нужно, как я понимаю:

- Отловить `клик` по элементу с
     определенным классом. Произвести с
     ним какие-то действия.
- Отловить
     `нажатие` "назад" и сэмулировать клик
     по определенному элементу.

По идее вам нужна общая функция как для `клика`, так и для `popstate`.

В тексте много воды, ничего не понятно, вот никто и не хочет читать это.

Comment: Перечитал свой текст, правда порой довольно непонятно. Сегодня вечером изменю его. Вы, в целом, в общем-то правильно поняли.